# How to delete data of Big Objects? (Preferably via Anonymous Apex)

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

I have some sample data in my Booking Big Object and now I want to delete the records so I tried writing this in Anonymous Apex:

```
List<Booking__b> booking = new List<Booking__b>(); 
booking.addAll([SELECT Channel__c FROM Booking__b]); 
Database.deleteImmediate(booking);
```

but get the below error :

```
System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 000000000000000AAA; first error: INVALID_ARGUMENT_TYPE, You must include only the entire set of indexed columns in the example set for entity Booking. No other columns are allowed. : []
```

I have looked at this question [Are deletes allowed for Big Objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/199911/38191) but it did not satisfy me.

Please help?

Comment: what index fields do you have on `Booking__b`. Are all they included in the selection ? `[SELECT Channel__c FROM Booking__b]`

Comment: I had like 50 fields, so I just added all to the SOQL but still same error. In the end I just deleted the whole damn object and re-deployed the metadata

Comment: Did you read this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_delete.htm) about deleting records of Big Objects ?

Comment: Yes, I even copied their example of how to delete on anon apex, added all the index fields still get that error.

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi Can you help me test this? I tried creating a new big object and just 1 index field, querying it then deleting a record still gives me same error